# How do I sort my downloaded PS3 games by size?

Tags: ps3

I'm out of space on my PlayStation 3 and would like to remove the games with the largest download sizes. I don't see an option to sort by size. Is there some way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible as far as I know.
You can try to start from this [list of games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PlayStation_3_games):
The individual games' pages are supposed to have the install sizes in them.
Depending on the number of games, this might take a while.

This however doesn't solve the problem with respect to patches, as some games have really huge patches. For example, I remember "Need for Speed Most Wanted" downloading a patch with more than 2 GB, so you should also check the "Game Data (PS3)" section on your console.

I know this is all pretty unsatisfactory, so I personally chose to not download all the PS Plus games anymore and just look for 1-2 bigger games and/or install data to delete whenever I need space for new games.